# typescript equivalent for python dataclass with init=False

Tags: typescript

I want to write class data members inside the class constructor

```js
class Person
{
    constructor
    (
        private name: string,
        private salary: number,
        public grades: Map<string, number> = new Map([["calculus", 100]])
    ){}
}

var p = new Person("oren", 7400, new Map());
//                               ^^^^^^^^^
console.log(p.grades.get("calculus"));
```

But prevent users to provide some parameters (`grades` here)

```
% npx tsc --esModuleInterop example.ts
% node example.js                     
undefined # <--- should be 100 ...
```

Comment: If you don't want it as a constructor parameter, why not just **not** take it as a constructor parameter? [Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEAKCmAnCB7AdgKAN4en6ADgK4BGIAlsNAOaJgAm8EAXNALJgEA8EALouTTUANNDREAtiSQA+aAF4x8AO7tOACgDamgETAwIYERBEIO0QEYADFYC6tgJQZc+YOj6IiwXikQu86v74eAQCAG5gvPBiYBLwrB6CIkHBoeQRUdAQBmCIAJ6s4lJIwkEOWAC+GFUYEYiECkqqCMjo6jq+8Gjm0ADsACw2omgqagTqDg4A3BgA9LPBi0vLK9AAehubmxhuaKgg8AB0ICjU6gSHtAxMl-C87fqGxqY6k1NAA)

Comment: @VLAZ I wanted to avoid spreading the data members around - Ideally they should be all in the same place

Comment: Well, you either want it as a constructor parameter (as you declared it now) or you don't and change your code. There is no middle ground. Saying "I want it as a constructor parameter just because it saves me a tiny little bit of code but it's not actually a constructor parameter" is not supported.